# Laravel notifications does not store column data

Tags: laravel

Notifications are not recording data in the database. I tried it with `toDatabase` and it also didn't work. Look:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NovoSeguidor extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    private $user;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(user $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail','database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line("Novo seguidor: {$this->user}")
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'teste' => 'Hello',
        ];
    }
}
```

My column `data` return `[]`.

I tried both ways, both using `toArray()` and `toDatabase()`, both return an empty array.

I've tried everything and I don't see anything that could be causing it. Can anyone help me identify the problem?

Comment: Same problem, using Laravel 7. On my local machine it works; on our staging environment not, which points to an issue with the infrastructure or with the .env file. Could you resolve the issue?

I'm currently debugging the issue by looking into the Laravel code. I found out that the functions in `src/Illuminate/Notifications/DatabaseChannel.php` are not executed (`send`, `buildPayload`, `getData`). I'll post my observations/solution here.